# Why is Collections.binarySearch giving wrong results?

Tags: java, collections, binary-search

I have created a List where I have kept some strings. But when I am doing **binary search** within this list, it is returning **negative values** while the item is **in the list**.

So far my knowledge **positive value** will be returned when item **in the list**. But for some items it is returning negative and for some items positive.

**Code:**

```
@Test
public void hello()
{
//  List<String> arlst = new ArrayList<String>();
    List arlst = new ArrayList();
    arlst.add("TP");
    arlst.add("PROVIDES");
    arlst.add("QUALITY");
    arlst.add("TUTORIALS");
    arlst.add("Stop");
    arlst.add("StopP");
    for (Iterator<String> iterator = (Iterator<String>) arlst.iterator();
            iterator.hasNext();)
    {
        Object next = iterator.next();
        System.out.println("next : " + next + " >> Search result : "
            + Collections.binarySearch(arlst, next.toString()));
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```
next : TP >> Search result : -7
next : PROVIDES >> Search result : -1
next : QUALITY >> Search result : 2
next : TUTORIALS >> Search result : -7
next : Stop >> Search result : 4
next : StopP >> Search result : 5
```

Comment: binary search requires the List to be sorted.

Comment: Note that you shouldn't use **raw-types**. Write `List<String>`, not `List`. Latter converts to `List<Object>` and in almost every application you want to restrict elements to a common type, like `String`. And even if not, then at least write `List<Object>` instead of raw-types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Reason

You receive strange values since your `List` is **not sorted** prior to calling the method, but this is a **requirement**. Therefore take a look at the methods [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch-java.util.List-T-):

> Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list **must be sorted into ascending order** according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) **prior** to making this call. If it is **not sorted**, the results are **undefined**. If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found.

---

### Explanation

In order to understand that requirement you need to understand how binary search works. Here is a small illustration:

[image: Binary search illustration]

The algorithm takes a look at the element in the middle and compares it to the element to search for. If the given needle is less than the middle element it will continue search to the left, else to the right. It will now take a look at the element to the middle of the reduced range and repeat this process until the element was found or the range can't be divided anymore.

If the elements are not sorted prior, the algorithm will very likely traverse to the **wrong direction** and obviously not find the element.

---

### Solution

The solution is obvious, sort the `List`:

```
Collections.sort(arlst);
```

Please note that you should **not use raw-types**. Therefore, write `List<String>` instead of just `List`. Then your type-casts will become obsolete too.

In complete the code might then look like

```
// Setup list
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
list.add("TP");
list.add("PROVIDES");
list.add("QUALITY");
list.add("TUTORIALS");
list.add("Stop");
list.add("StopP");

// Sort list
Collections.sort(list);

// Iterate all elements and use binary search
Iterator<String> iter = list.iterator();
while (iter.hasNext()) {
    String element = iter.next();
    System.out.println("element : " + element
        + " >> Search result : "
        + Collections.binarySearch(list, element));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

List must be sorted to use binarySearch on it.

Answer (score 0):

In the API specification:

**Searches the specified list for the specified object using the binary search algorithm. The list must be sorted into ascending order according to the natural ordering of its elements (as by the sort(List) method) prior to making this call. *If it is not sorted, the results are undefined*. If the list contains multiple elements equal to the specified object, there is no guarantee which one will be found**